# php an user should login in one system and should not be able to login from other system unless requested

Tags: php, session

1. I want to allow users to use only one system to login.
2. if they use another machine then they should not be able to login.
3. If they want to login then they can click request login option which will sent a reset link to the users email which when clicked will reset and update the database so that from now on he can login form that machine form which he made the reset request.
4. so, when ever the user changes his machine he should not be able to login and can request a reset option.
5. i am using ip and session id and previous session id to check login from one machine.
6. if his session expires in that machine he will be logged in next time by storing the previous session id reference in a cookie.
7. so each time he access there will be two cookies to mean that whether he previously logged in this machine and if so then the session id is updated and he is logged in.

   so if he is login in from a  machine and if there is no previous/current session-id/ip-address then he is considered totally new to that machine and he cannot login.

   Hope i have made it clear. if it is not much clear then please comment then i will edit my question.

   I want a better approach or some other efficient mechanism to implement such functionality.

   **Even if the client is in a lan all the above conditions apply.**

   **do my way of doing this has complications? if so then please suggest a good one.**

   Thank you.

---

**Editing after a comment from** https://stackoverflow.com/users/164394/purplepilot

---

the user can login anywhere but if the machine changes they can request an reset through their email. when they click the link in the email then that machines ip will be recorded and the user will have to continue in that system. This was requested by the admin cause there is going to be only two admin users.

Comment: my question would be why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Even if the client is in a lan all the above conditions apply.

Comment: In that case ask the client what they want as they seem to be really confused. Point 1 says only use one system. Point 2 says they cannot log in from another machine/system but point 3 says if it is another system then the login is reset and they can login from another machine. So the user who presumably cannot see all this going on can log in from any machine they want. Should the question be that how do you make it so a user can only log in once and only have one session. so the same user cannot login twice (or more) at the same time?

Comment: oh. the user can login anywhere but if the machine changes they can request an reset through their email. when they click the link in the email then that machines ip will be recorded and the user will have to continue in that system. This was requested by the admin cause there is going to be only two admin users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why dont you use cookie instead of session as your app demand that.**

**i think you are confused**

Session never stored in client , cookie does. so you have to think about cookie for this app. Logic for the project seems okey once you implement cookie instead of session.

Comment: haha... who wouldn't know about your first sentence. Even if the client is in a LAN all the above conditions apply.

Comment: ya even in LAN, as cookie work in individual machine with expiry time

Comment: Thank you. yes your answer is fine too. if cookie is totally disabled what would be the alternate? i hope that will go very tedious like sending all cookie data in the url encrypted isn't it?

Comment: i have added a little more description